# How do nested vpns through VM work?

Tags: vpn

Let's say I have 2 different VPN services (`vpn1` and `vpn2`) both using OpenVPN and a Linux host running a guest VM.

Now let's suppose I connect from the Linux host to `vpn1`. Then I connect from the guest VM to `vpn2` and I browse the Internet from there.
The situation, I suppose, should look like this (but I'm not sure):

```
host --> VPN 1 --> Internet      
     guest --> VPN 2 --> target
```

My questions are:

1. Does `vpn2` know my IP?
2. Can `vpn1` see the web sites I am visiting?

Comment: If I understood your setup, then your diagram is not accurate. You are tunneling VPN2 within VPN1 (assuming the appropriate network setup). Then for question #1, which IP are you asking about?

Comment: I'm referring to the public IP used by the linux box. Is it visible by both vpns or only one?

Comment: That is going to depend on how you have set up your networking, actually. I think the deeper answer to your question is, "how do I set up the nested VPN so that it uses the parent VPN as a native network connection?" That's going to depend on the VM technology used and how you have configured the host. For that question, you will find more experts on ServerFault.SE

Comment: I made a tentative diagram change according to what I understand your setup to be.